# Get years between two dates in jQuery

Tags: jquery, date

I need to get all years between two dates in jQuery
For example if I have these two dates ("2014-5-1" , "2017-4-6"), I need to get all of years between them like this (2014, 2015, 2016, 2017)
so can any one help me with this please
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would return an array with the years

```
function getYears(from, to) {
    var d1 = new Date(from),
        d2 = new Date(to),
        yr = [];

    for (var i=d1.getFullYear(); i<=d2.getFullYear(); i++) {
        yr.push( i );
    }

    return yr;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/58w7Lpnp/)

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery needed.

```js
var y1 = new Date("2014-5-1").getFullYear();
var y2 = new Date("2017-4-6").getFullYear();

var years = [];
if(y1 < y2){
  for(var i = y1; i <= y2; i++){
    years.push(i);
    }
  }
else{
  for(var i = y2; i <= y1; i++){
    years.push(i);
    }
  }
console.log(years);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you properly format your dates it can be done with JavaScript Date object.

```
function calculateYears(date1, date2){
    date1 = new Date(date1);
    date2 = new Date(date2);
    var period = date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear();
    if (date2.getMonth() < date1.getMonth() - 1){
        period--;
    }
    if (date1.getMonth() - 1 == date2.getMonth() && date2.getDate() < date1.getDate()){
        period--;
    };
  return period;
};
console.log(calculateYears("2014-05-01" , "2017-04-06"));
```

Comment: Eventhough this is not the solution for the question, it's still nice and simple function. Why do you subtract 1 from `date1.getMonth()`? Both values are already 0-based, so without that subtraction it would return actual full years.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tm1q4jsb/2/)

```
var getyears = function(firstdate, seconddate){
    var firstyear = firstdate.getFullYear();
    var secondyear = seconddate.getFullYear();
    for(var i=firstyear;i<=secondyear;i++) {
        alert(i);
    };

};
$('#getyears').click(function(){
    alert('get years');
    getyears(new Date("2014/5/1") , new Date("2017/4/6"));
});
```